# ASP. Net Core add native library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, tesseract

Just started messing with the asp.net 5. I am using full stack .net framework (dnx46)

Trying to add Tesseract .net library. 
I've added nuget package but it also want native libraries to be present. The package itself relies on native libraries. It looks like library itself decided where to look for binarires (86 / 64 folders)

Here is the demo from GitHub repo 
https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/Samples/Tesseract.WebDemo

I can't figure out how to put x86 and x64 folders at the my project dll for the to be visible for app

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully tesseract dev left a configuration opportunity.

That is how its done:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build().ReloadOnChanged("appsettings.json");

        var basePath = applicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
        var libPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "approot");
        LibraryLoader.Instance.CustomSearchPath = libPath;
        TessDataPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "approot\\tessdata");
    }
...

}
```

...

Usage:

```
    using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(Startup.TessDataPath, "eng"))
    {

    }
```